# I'm getting a Run-Time Error 5 When creating a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

i'm quite new to VBA and to StackOverflow in general.
I'm trying to creat a pivot table but i get an error related to my "set pt" line, or at least that's where the code breaks.

```
Sub PivotTable()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ptCache As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ptRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ptLocation As Range

'Work with the active file
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'set the range where my data is
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lastCol = ws.Cells(ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'set the range the pivot will work with
Set ptRange = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

'where my pivot will be
Set ptLocation = ws.Cells(lastRow + 5, 2)

'set my pivot cache
Set ptCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ptRange)

'create the pivot table
Set pt = ptCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ptLocation, TableName:="MyPivotTable")

With pt
    .PivotFields("Booking").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Htl Cost").Orientation = xlDataField
    
End With
End Sub
```

not sure what it could be or what to do.
I've been battling with this one a while, any help would be much appreciated.

this works in a specific workbook and worksheet, but when i changed the reference of ws to be "ActiveSheet", that's when it broke down.
The thing is that i need this macro to be part of my personal workbook, so i can use it in multiple files.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` points to your personal, try `ws.parent`

Comment: You should add the `PivotCache` to the active workbook, not `ThisWorkbook`.